# Openstack Juno Cinder Stuck at Snapshot

Tags: 14.04, juju, openstack

Having difficulties with taking a snapshot from an image. I am using cinder-9 charm with loop back storage:

```
# losetup -a
/dev/loop0: [0801]:2232155 (/var/lib/cinder/volumes/vol1.img)
# pvdisplay 
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/loop0
  VG Name               cinder-volumes
  PV Size               5.00 GiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              1279
  Free PE               1023
  Allocated PE          256
  PV UUID               hUZybu-S6Vr-Gx1E-MtHo-72wn-oW1v-TSh0ny
# vgdisplay 
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               cinder-volumes
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  6
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               5.00 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              1279
  Alloc PE / Size       256 / 1.00 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       1023 / 4.00 GiB
  VG UUID               LRqwVp-xibZ-W9TC-XG5q-7ZgK-qiOW-dl5VeF
```

"block-device" menu, in charm gui, has the following entry:

```
/var/lib/cinder/volumes/vol1.img|5G
```

Similarly, "volume-group" specifies:

```
cinder-volumes
```

After powering off a VM - TrustyGstrm :

```
# nova list
+--------------------------------------+-------------+---------+------------+-------------+--------------------------------+
| ID                                   | Name        | Status  | Task State | Power State | Networks                       |
+--------------------------------------+-------------+---------+------------+-------------+--------------------------------+
| 2bd319fb-b6dd-4541-a595-64ee85d5bb70 | TrustyGstrm | SHUTOFF | -          | Shutdown    | priv2=10.10.200.4, 10.0.200.52 |
| a43735cb-8368-4202-8425-cb8c8a66ad96 | t1          | ACTIVE  | -          | Running     | priv2=10.10.200.2, 10.0.200.51 |
+--------------------------------------+-------------+---------+------------+-------------+--------------------------------+
# cinder list
+--------------------------------------+-----------+--------------+------+-------------+----------+-------------+
|                  ID                  |   Status  | Display Name | Size | Volume Type | Bootable | Attached to |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+--------------+------+-------------+----------+-------------+
| 0f60862e-258d-417c-979e-e5e3e3cde516 | available |     None     |  1   |     None    |  false   |             |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+--------------+------+-------------+----------+-------------+
```

And starting the snapshot, it gets stuck at 25%:

```
# nova image-create --poll TrustyGstrm TrustyGstrmSn

Server snapshotting... 25% complete
```

I can't see anything significant in the log files:

```
# tail -f /var/log/cinder/cinder-volume.log
2014-12-03 20:09:35.160 6236 INFO cinder.volume.manager [-] Updating volume status
2014-12-03 20:09:35.278 6236 INFO cinder.volume.manager [-] Updating volume replication status.
2014-12-03 20:10:35.166 6236 INFO cinder.volume.manager [-] Updating volume status
2014-12-03 20:10:35.292 6236 INFO cinder.volume.manager [-] Updating volume replication status.
2014-12-03 20:11:35.173 6236 INFO cinder.volume.manager [-] Updating volume status
2014-12-03 20:11:35.294 6236 INFO cinder.volume.manager [-] Updating volume replication
```

Services seem to be up:

```
# cinder service-list
+------------------+----------------------+------+---------+-------+----------------------------+-----------------+
|      Binary      |         Host         | Zone |  Status | State |         Updated_at         | Disabled Reason |
+------------------+----------------------+------+---------+-------+----------------------------+-----------------+
| cinder-scheduler |        cinder        | nova | enabled |   up  | 2014-12-03T20:21:36.000000 |       None      |
| cinder-scheduler | juju-machine-4-lxc-0 | nova | enabled |  down | 2014-11-23T09:08:47.000000 |       None      |
|  cinder-volume   |        cinder        | nova | enabled |   up  | 2014-12-03T20:21:36.000000 |       None      |
|  cinder-volume   | juju-machine-4-lxc-0 | nova | enabled |  down | 2014-11-23T09:08:49.000000 |       None      |
+------------------+----------------------+------+---------+-------+----------------------------+-----------------+
```

(juju-machine-4-lxc-0, is a decommissioned machine. I don't know how to get rid of it.)

Any thoughts?

Edit 1:
This ALWAYS gets me! Make sure that your loopback storage size is larger than your flavour disk size! (A warning would be nice)